# Could not find the config file

Tags: ssis, biml

I have a BIMl file produces the following error
Could not find a part of the path

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\BIMLtemplate\config\config.xml'
```

I tried opening and closing the application even restarted my system.

Comment: If we eliminate putting the configuration file in a Windows subdirectory, does the problem remain? Also, a minimal reproduction of what you're doing would be helpful